# Why does `changes` return `Event t (Future a)`

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

The [`changes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.0.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html#v:changes) function has type `Frameworks t => Behavior t a -> Moment t (Event t (Future a))`. `Future` is abstract and there is only one function that consumes it (`reactimate'`).

However, I can easily write the following function:

```
changes' :: Frameworks t => Behavior t a -> Moment t (Event t a)
changes' b = fmap (fmap const b <@>) (changes b)
```

to get a normal (non-`Future`) event.

Is something wrong with that function? If not, why does the original `changes` function have a more restrictive type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `changes` returns different values than the function `changes'` that you describe. The key point is the following:

Consider a Behavior defined by `stepper` (or `accumB`), which happens to change at time *t0*. What value does the Behavior have at this moment in time? The answer is that the Behavior takes on the new value for all times that are *strictly larger* than the time of change, *t > t0*, and that it still has its old value at time *t0*. In other words, the `changes'` function returns an event whose values are the old values of the Behavior at the time of change. In contrast, the `changes` function returns the new ("future") values. For various reasons that have to do with [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852344/403805), the new values are wrapped in a `Future` type, so that they cannot be accessed until the `reactimate'` phase.

EDIT: Tobias has drawn a picture for illustration:

[image]

Comment: Linked to it from the answer. :-)